# Is there a way to use stanford-nlp-pos-tagger in a .NET project in UWP. If not what are the alternatives

Tags: uwp, nlp, stanford-nlp

While trying to install Stanford.NLP.POSTagger in .NET project in Universal Windows Platform, I get this error:

> NU1202: Package Stanford.NLP.POSTagger 3.9.2 is not compatible with uap10.0.15063 (UAP,Version=v10.0.15063). Package
>   Stanford.NLP.POSTagger 3.9.2 supports: net
>   (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0)
>   NU1202: Package IKVM 8.1.5717 is not compatible with uap10.0.15063 (UAP,Version=v10.0.15063). Package IKVM 8.1.5717 supports: net
>   (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0)

Is there a work around for this? Or I might use some other POS tagger libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try upgrading your UWP project to target **at least SDK 16299 (Fall Creators Update)**. This way the library could be referenced. Unfortunately it means you will not be able to support Windows 10 Mobile.

Right-click your UWP project in Solution Explorer and select Properties. There you select the **Min** and **Target** versions to at least 16299.

[image: Targeting drop downs]